# Astro.js Image Sharp error + sanity integration

Tags: sanity, astrojs

I am trying to create a simple web app using Astro that will have headless CMS using Sanity.

I was having issues with Astro Image component when trying to use it with statically imported image - That I needed to install Sharp manualy (I am using yarn"). After some googling I have fixed that using: "yarn add sharp --ignore-engines". But when I tried to deploy the app on vercel it couldnt deploy due to same error. How do I fix this sharp error during vercel build? Localy it works fine for me now.

```
  Error reference:
    https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/errors/could-not-transform-image/
  Stack trace:
    at generateImageInternal (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/astro/dist/assets/build/generate.js:129:21)
    at async file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/p-queue/dist/index.js:187:36
  Caused by:
  Could not find Sharp. Please install Sharp (`sharp`) manually into your project or migrate to another image service.
    at loadSharp (file:///vercel/path0/dist/chunks/astro/assets-service_qO_yPtYB.mjs:289:11)
    at async generateImageInternal (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/astro/dist/assets/build/generate.js:123:26)
    at async file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/p-queue/dist/index.js:187:36
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Another question is that I have setup sanity in astro.config.mjs:

```
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [tailwind(), sanityIntegration({
    projectId:"projectId",
    dataset:"production",
    useCdn:true,
    apiVersion:"2024-01-07",
  }), react(),]
});
```

But when I want to use sanity in astro page e.g. movies.astro like this.

```
import { sanityClient } from "sanity:client";
const posts = await sanityClient.fetch(`*[_type == "movie"]`);
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'sanity:client' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Why this error happens? The interesting part is that I can use sanityClient and it works, it just shows this error.

Comment: which npm packages did you install? maybe post your `package.json`? sounds like you should install [`@sanity/client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sanity/client), or alternatively use the [REST API](https://www.sanity.io/docs/http-api) directly... Not sure why you think you'd need to install Sharp...

Comment: I have following deps in my package.json

  "dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/check": "^0.3.4",
    "@astrojs/react": "^3.0.9",
    "@astrojs/tailwind": "^5.1.0",
    "@sanity/astro": "^2.2.0",
    "@sanity/client": "^6.10.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.47",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "astro": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sanity": "^3.23.4",
    "sharp": "^0.33.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },

The error message hinted me to install Sharp, thats why I opted to install it.

Comment: Ah yes, [installing sharp is apparently expected](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/errors/missing-sharp/). Do you use `npm` or `pnpm`? if the former, make sure to commit your `package-lock.json`...

regarding sanity, you don't want to install the package `sanity`, but `@sanity/client` I think...